# Non Consumable IAP buy twice on Android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm having a question about android consumable IAP.

What happens, when:

1. Install the app
2. Buy a consumable product
3. Uninstall the app
4. Install again
5. Try to buy the consumable again

In the sandbox mode it shows like a completely new transaction. (not like on iOS)
On iOS it's work expected, when the user try to buy again "You have already purchased this."  shows up.

So my question is that what happen when the user try to buy a non consumable product again on android?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041039/how-to-setup-in-app-purchase-non-consumable)

Comment: I checked, but after uninstall you don't have store receipt until the user tap the "restore purchase" button. I can't hide the button because i don't have any information about user's purchases.

Comment: It is linked to user email which is being used in google play.

Comment: I know, but the question is that what happen when the user try to buy an already purchased item? Is there any mechanism which prevent the second try?